# spring-session-jdbcのトランザクションをAutoCommitにしたい

Tags: java, spring-boot, ajax, session, jdbc

ajaxで呼び出す長い処理（CSVファイルアップロード）の処理状況N/Mを一定間隔で取得したい（これもajax)のですが、どうも、セッションがコミットされていないような感じで状況が取得できません。
spring-session-jdbcを適用する前は期待通りの動作をしていました。

メイン処理の処理状況を覗くようなajaxってどのように作成したらいいでしょうか？

調査してて関係ありそうなページは
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/464
や
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/config/annotation/web/http/JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java
あたりだと思っているのですがどう書いたらいいのか・・・

MainController

```
    // MainController
@PostMapping("/main/uploadCsv")
@ResponseBody
public ResultDto upload(
        HttpServletRequest request
        , @RequestParam("csvFile") MultipartFile csvFile) throws IOException {

    // 処理状況の初期化
    ProgressDto progress;
    synchronized (session) {
        if (session.getAttribute("progress") != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("処理中です。");
        }
        progress = new ProgressDto();
        progress.totalCount = 0;
        progress.current = 0;
        progress.setStatus("Processing");
        session.setAttribute("progress", progress);
    }

    // CSVアップロード
    ResultDto result = csvService.uploadCsv(csvFile);

    // CSVファイル読み込み
    csvService.readCsvFile(result);
    progress.totalCount = result.getUploadDetails().size();
    session.setAttribute("progress", progress);

    // CSVファイル内容チェック
    csvService.checkCsvFile(session, result, progress);
    // 進捗状況
    progress.setStatus("Complete");
    // 結果をセッションに格納
    session.setAttribute("result", result);
    session.setAttribute("progress", progress);

    return result;
}
```

CsvService

```
// CsvService
public ResultDto uploadCsv(MultipartFile csvFile) throws IOException {
    ResultDto result = new ResultDto();
    // 出力先フォルダ
    Path uploadPath = Paths.get("csv");
    // CSVファイル出力
    File destinationFile = new File(uploadPath.toString(), csvFile.getOriginalFilename());
    InputStream inputStream = csvFile.getInputStream();
    Files.copy(inputStream, destinationFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    // 出力結果
    result.setCsvFilePath(destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
    result.setCsvFileName(csvFile.getOriginalFilename());
    result.setCsvFileSize(csvFile.getSize());
    return result;
}

public void readCsvFile(ResultDto result) throws Exception {
    List<UploadDetailBean> details = new ArrayList<>();
    File csvFile = new File(result.getCsvFilePath());
    try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        CsvToBeanBuilder<UploadDetailBean> builder = new CsvToBeanBuilder<>(csvReader);
        builder.withType(UploadDetailBean.class);
        details = builder.build().parse();
        // BOM削除
        if (!details.isEmpty()) {
            UploadDetailBean detail = details.get(0);
            if (detail.getLineNumber() != null && detail.getLineNumber().startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
                detail.setLineNumber(detail.getLineNumber().substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
    result.setUploadDetails(details);
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void checkCsvFile(HttpSession session, ResultDto result, ProgressDto progress) {
    List<UploadDetailBean> details = result.getUploadDetails();
    for (ListIterator<UploadDetailBean> iterator = details.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        UploadDetailBean detail = iterator.next();

        UploadForm form = new UploadForm(detail);
        // フォームのバリデーションチェック
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UploadForm>> errorResults = validator.validate(form);
        String message = "";
        for (ConstraintViolation<UploadForm> errorResult : errorResults) {
            message += errorResult.getMessage() + "\n";
        }
        if (!errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            detail.setProcess("失敗");
            detail.setMessage(message);
        } else {
            // DBチェック
            TableEntity tableEntity = csvMap.getById(detail.getId());
            if (tableEntity == null) {
                detail.setProcess("追加");
                csvMap.insert(detail);
            } else {
                detail.setProcess("更新");
                csvMap.update(detail);
            }
        }

        // 進捗状況
        progress.setCurrent(detail.getLineNumber());
        session.setAttribute("progress", progress);
    }
}
```

MainController

```
// MainController
@PostMapping("/csv/progress")
@ResponseBody
public ProgressDto progress(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // 処理状況の取得
    return (ProgressDto)session.getAttribute("progress");
}
```

Comment: [`spring.session.jdbc.flush-mode`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.session.jdbc.flush-mode) を [`immediate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/3.2.0/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/FlushMode.java#L35-L42) に設定すれば良さそうに見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます‼️無事解決できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

出羽さんありがとうございます。
spring.session.jdbc.flush-mode を immediate に設定して解決できました。